# Visual Studios Express missing cpp and header files for add new item

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I am fairly new to programming with visual studios and c++. I currently installed VS express 2015 (VS 14), and when I create a new project and click add new item on either the source files or header files, no pre installed templates are showing up. I watched some videos and read some documents and most of them had .cpp and .h file options. When I did some research on my own about the problem, there was a way to fix it using the registry but the bug was found for VS 2012, and the bug has been removed since. I don't really want to mess with my registry, but is there a reason why this is happening. If there is a solution please give me step by step instructions. Thank you

Comment: You may need to install visual-c++ separately, I don't think it comes "pre-packaged" with VS2015 Express. There should be an option to "Install VC++ Tools" or something along those lines when you try to create a project. Also, as Richard mentions below, it would be best to use VS2015 Community now.

Comment: I suggest you concider upgrading to Visual Studio Community 2015 https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx

Comment: I agree with Richard Critten. I use that without issues.

Comment: Thank-you, I have started using visual studios community and there is nothing wrong. I appreciate the quick response